# Unable to set the props value while sending data to parent from child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get data from child components to parent component:
I have implemented like the below in my parent component:

```
<Table getTotalSelectedId={this.getTotalSelectedId}/>
```

and defined method as such:

```
 getTotalSelectedTransactionId=data =>{
    console.log("Selected Transaction Id are",data);//This is blank
  }
```

Child Component:

```
var totalSelected=[];//defined as global
 selectAll = () => {
    this.setState({ selectAll: !this.state.selectAll }, () => {
      var collection=[];
     if(this.state.selectAll == true){
    for (const item of this.state.items) {
        collection.push(item.TransactionID);
        this.setState({checkedListAll:collection});
       }
    }
    else{
      collection=[];
      this.setState({checkedListAll:collection});
    }
    totalSelected=collection;
      console.log("Total selected Transaction Id are:",totalSelected);//This has value
      let items = [...this.state.items];
      items = items.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          checked: this.state.selectAll
        };
      });
     this.setState({ items });
    });
    this.props.getTotalSelectedId(totalSelected);//Setting the value in props
  };
```

The value "data" in the parent component is coming as empty.
Can anyone explain where i am going wrong?

Comment: so `data` in your parent component is an empty array?

Comment: yes...data is displayed as an empty array

Comment: if  this.state.items would be an empty , console.log("Total selected Transaction Id are:",totalSelected)...this would not have been giving us the value

Comment: yes....hence why i removed my comment.

Comment: yeah!! where it is going wrong...any idea??

Comment: i guess `totalSelected` is reset to an empty array at one time

Comment: Can you share more code from child component?

Comment: Try this <Table getTotalSelectedId={this. getTotalSelectedTransactionId}/>

Comment: see in setState callback you have assigned `totalSelected=collection` but `this.props.getTotalSelectedId(totalSelected);` is called in selectAll function last line. kindly move `this.props.getTotalSelectedId(totalSelected)` inside setState callback function

Comment: Thanks @sarvon ks ,i got to know where I was wrong!!

Comment: Here I can get the value but the purpose of this method was to check all the checkboxes in table where it is failing now

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
   <Table getTotalSelectedId={this. getTotalSelectedTransactionId}/>
```

I think you are referring to wrong method.